# При запуске exe файла через cmd, не находит библиотеку imageio из библиотеки moviepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, exe, moviepy

Для своих целей мне нужно сделать из python файла exe. Делаю я это при помощи auto-py-to-exe и компилирую одним файлом. В моем коде есть импорт библиотек: `from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip` и `import openpyxl`. Проблема заключается в том, что exe файл не может найти первую библиотеку и выходит ошибка, если запускать exe через cmd.
Вот ошибка, если запускать exe:

```
D:\Python\ide>converter.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "moviepy\editor.py", line 24, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageio'
[8868] Failed to execute script 'converter' due to unhandled exception!
```

Если запускать py файл через intellij idea или через cmd, то все библиотеки находятся и код полностью работает. Это код для конвертации mp4 в mp3 или gif, который работает при помощи exel (использовать exel и компилировать этот py файл в exe нужно обязательно).

Итак, фулл код:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import openpyxl

def gifer(link, name_conv):
    clip = (VideoFileClip(link)
            .resize(0.3))
    clip.write_gif(name_conv + ".gif")

def converttomp3(link, name_conv):
    video=VideoFileClip(link)
    audio=video.audio
    audio.write_audiofile(name_conv + ".mp3")
    audio.close()
    video.close()

book = openpyxl.open("main.xlsx", read_only=True)
sheet = book.active

link = sheet["B1"].value
type_conv= sheet["B2"].value
name_conv = sheet["B3"].value

if type_conv == "MP3":
    converttomp3(link, name_conv)
elif type_conv == "GIF":
    gifer(link, name_conv)
else:
    print("ERROR")
```

**В итоге, как правильно мне скомпилировать python файл в exe и куда закинуть библиотеку moviepy, чтобы она свободно находилась.** Все библиотеки установлены и находятся пайтон файлом, однако exe приложение найти их не может.

Comment: а куда вы ее устанавливали? очевидно что скрипт ее не видит

Comment: exe файл я скомпилировал в ту же папку, в которой py файл, т.е. все пути и директории те же самые

Comment: при чем тут это, если вы не можете запустить программу из за ошибки, `.exe` очевидно не запустится

Comment: да, но сама программа работает. не работает только exe, т.к. он не может найти библиотеку. но при этом py файл, находящиеся в той же директории спокойно все находит и работает

Comment: Как вы сделали из скрипта исполняемый файл?

Comment: скомпилировал файл py в exe с помощью auto-py-to-exe и запустил готовый exe файл через cmd

Comment: в вашей изначальной редакции говорилось, что ни `.py` ни `.exe` не запускаются.  отвечал я исходя из этих слов. попробуйте создать виртуальное окружение, установить туда что надо и попробовать из него

Comment: хорошо, попробую, спасибо